# Populating fields in Visual Workflow screen using record data

Tags: visual-workflow

Is there any way to populate the fields of a Visual Workflow screen using data from a record lookup? I cannot seem to find a straight answer.

The particular use case, if you want to chime in, is as follows. I am creating a lead submission flow that checks for duplicates. After presenting potential duplicates, I offer the user the option to edit it. The quick-and-dirty way is to form a URL that the user clicks to go and edit the record herself. The nicer way of implementing it would be to fetch the data of the existing record, populate a set of screen fields and write the values back into the record once the user is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catalandres - as you stated you can use variables in the default field.  This includes sObject.Field variables as well, or other screen input fields from previous steps.

Screen shot of default values:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Default Value" setting for screen fields takes variables. It suffices to create variables to store the values imported from the record lookup and add the variables as the default value of the corresponding fields.

Comment: You can also use an sObject variable for a specific record of that type and retrieve the sObject fields into the screen fields.

Comment: @DaveHumm Your answer is actually more compact and easier to maintain. Thanks!